# How do I resolve this missing crystal reports assembly?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I inherited a project for a colleague who left and it looks to be some older asp.net code. I installed the Microsoft Report Viewer and the SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio and I am still stuck on this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

On the page that throws the error, there is a Register tag for something to do with Crystal Reports:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CR" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" %>
```

In the system.webserver section, the second line specifies some kind of aspx file that I don't see in the project, but it refers to a version 10 of the assembly that VS can't find.

```
<system.webServer>
  <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>-->
  <handlers>
    <add name="ASPHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64"/>
    <add name="CrystalImageHandler-aspx" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" verb="GET" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
    <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
    <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
    <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
    <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
    <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

In the web.config, in the assembly bindings section, I found this:

```
<runtime xmlns="">
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3500.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

So, is it actually looking for version 13 of Crystal Reports?